# Doing CountDistinct on two or more Fields in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have Crystal Report DistinctCount function, and i want to convert it to SSRS CountDistinct
The below expression is in Crystal Report;

> {Prod.mID} + "     Total Patients: " + Totext(DistinctCount({Prod.A},{Prod.B}),0,"")

I have made this so far, but not able to implement it in SSRS report;

> =Fields!B.Value & "Total Patients: " & CountDistinct(cstr(Fields!A.Value) + cstr(Fields!B.Value),0,"")

Any suggestions as to how to achieve this. Where am i going wrong.
Appreciate it.

Comment: Can anyone help me out with this please. I am at the verge of completing my Report, except this one, where i am stuck and its blowing my head off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the Crystal Reports DistintCount works but the 2nd (optional) argument for the SSRS CountDistinct function is for the group Scope and the 3rd is whether it's recursive. I don't think you need either (if you do, they are flipped around).

```
=Fields!B.Value & "Total Patients: " & CountDistinct(cstr(Fields!A.Value) & cstr(Fields!B.Value))
```

[MSDN - CountDistinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd255245(v=sql.110).aspx)